# Does this "Clear" function prevent SQL injection?

Tags: php, sql, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

php get var clear is it good or not plz help me

```
function Clear($text)
    $Var = str_replace("'", "", $text);
    $Var = str_replace('"', '', $Var);
    $Var = strip_tags($Var);
    $Var = htmlentities($Var);
    return $Var;
}
$_GET['Var'] = "1='1'";
$Var = Clear($_GET['Var']);
$Query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COL ='{$Var}'";
echo 'Result : '.($Query);
```

it is for SQL injection, this is sample code i wrote iam using pdo. if i using mysql_real_escape_string it dose not working.

Comment: Too Vague! What's ur problem?

Comment: I believe the question is whether using the `Clear()` method effectively prevents SQL injection.

Comment: i want get parameter to filter

Comment: Did you mean using $_GET is a good practice or not?

Comment: your question is not understandable, kindly clear your problem by editing your question

Comment: Using PDO's `prepare`, *it is already escaped*. It wouldn't be a good idea to double-escape it.

Answer (score 5):

**NO. NO. NO**

That is not "safe" from attacks.

At a **bare minimum** use `mysql_real_escape_string` (which is *designed* for this). The first version, `mysql_escape_string`, was [actually flawed](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8028/does-mysql-escape-string-have-any-security-vulnerabilities-if-all-tables-using-l) which is why the "real" version exists.

However, I *recommend placeholders* as a more universal (and tidier) solution.

See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) (which I am voting to close as a dupe, as well). The answers cover PDO and prepared statements, among other things.

Comment: @user1289782 there is no pdo in your sample code

Comment: I looked at that post and marked this question as an exact duplicate as well, to help :-) Unfortunately, I have reached my voting cap for the day, so I can't upvote...

Answer (score 2):

Use prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php